# Is this the correct syntax for a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull an array from a mysql table and put it into an html table. It works successfully but when I try and add the restriction `!= null`, no data is returned.

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "select * from timetable Where id = $id and Subject != NULL");
```

Comment: better is `is not null` instead of `!= NULL`

Comment: Make sure the value of `$id` comes only from controlled sources. Otherwise the query is open for [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection).

Comment: @axiac Its = to the session id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use equality operator with `NULL`. You should use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`
Example:

```
Subject IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Not sure about the reasoning behind the downvote. Any?